# Moq mock threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm working on unit test cases using `moq framework`
we have used `StructureMap` and `ObjectFactory` in our project for dependencies injection.

But When I try to Mock Interface which is not used with Object FActory

I'm getting following exception

> '((MyManager)MyManager)' threw an exception of
>   type 'System.ArgumentNullException'

Provided answer works for HomeController.cs methods , but what about those methods which are inside `MyManager.TestIdentity()`.
updated question accordingly.

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private IMyManager _myManager;
    public IMyManager MyManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _myManager ?? (new MyManager());
        }
        set { _myManager = value; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> TestMock()
    {           
      var response = await MyManager.TestIdentity("demo");
        if (response != null)
        {

            return Ok(identityResponse);
        }

        throw new ApiException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, 10001,
            "failed");
    }
}
```

MyManager.cs

```
public class MyManager : IMyManager
{
    private IMyRespository _myRepository;

    public IMyRespository MyRespository
    {
        get
        {
            return _myRepository;
        }
        set { _myRepository = value; }
    }

    public async Task<CustomerResponseObject> TestIdentity(string demo)
    {
        var result = await MyRespository.GetRoles("user");
    }
}
```

Now inside Unit Test project
I want to mock method `MyRespository.GetRoles`

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task CreateIdentityWithNullMag()
{
    try
    {            

  //I tried same mock with MyRespository.GetRoles
    var mockIMyRespository = new Mock<IMyRespository>();
            mockIMyRespository .Setup(p =>p.GetRoles(It.IsAny<string>())).
        ReturnsAsync(new RoleObject()
        {
            Name = "admin"
        });
    ObjectFactory.Inject(mockIMyRespository .Object);    


    var controller = new HomeController();
    //working for TestIdentity , failed for GetRoles , i mean GetRole method does not get Mock it has Null exception :(
    controller.MyManager = mockIMyManager.Object;

    await controller.TestMock(request); 

}
```

> 'MyRespository' threw an exception of
>   type 'System.ArgumentNullException'

What should be done? to success this Mock?

Comment: Show the example definitions for `IMyManager` and `IMyRespository` interfaces. Sure one can derive based on what is being shown what methods they have but lets remove assumptions so those trying to help you have a complete picture of what you are trying to do.

Comment: update we do not have any base there , how we can mock interanl methods any clue? thanks for help  in advance

Comment: If `HomeController` is the system under test then based on your current example there is no need for the repository. You only need to mock `IMyManager` as that is what `HomeController` depends.

Comment: yes but I get same exception of NULL exception If i tried to Mock IMyRespository method :(

Comment: But your example doesn't use `IMyRepository`. I don't understand. clarify.

Comment: ok let me update question correctly

Comment: please check I have updated question , issue is I want to mock methods which is inside MyManager.cs which uses IMyRepository property but like wise Homecontroller.cs it is not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `HomeController.MyManager` has a public setter, I'd use that:

```
var controller = new HomeController();
mockIMyManager.SetupGet(x=>x.MyRepository).Returns(mockIM‌​yRespository.Object)‌​;
controller.MyManager = mockIMyManager.Object;
await controller.TestMock(request);
```

Comment: This is working perfect for methods those are inside MyManager, but what about inside `TestIdentity` methods?
Suppose inside `TestIdentity` method I have `RepositoryData` method and want to mock it?

Comment: @Neo well you have not shown that in your example. This answer was based on the information provided and the assumption is that your example was a [mcve]

Comment: @Nkosi may I update my question ? or create new one?

Comment: @Neo, update your question and make sure it is a [mcve]

Comment: @Neo In your updated version, use `mockIMyManager.SetupGet(x=>x.MyRepository).Returns(mockIMyRespository.Object);`

Comment: I did not get you , could you please update your answer ? your first answers perfect for controller methods thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following based on your example

```
public interface IMyManager {
    Task<CustomerResponseObject> TestIdentity(string username);
}

public interface IMyRespository {
    Task<RoleObject> GetRole(string username);
}

public class RoleObject {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerResponseObject {
    public RoleObject Role { get; set; }
}
```

Where `MyManager` is the system under test

```
public class MyManager : IMyManager {
    private IMyRespository myRepository;

    public MyManager(IMyRespository myRepository) {
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
    }

    public async Task<CustomerResponseObject> TestIdentity(string username) {
        var role = await myRepository.GetRole(username);

        var result = new CustomerResponseObject {
            Role = role
        };
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here is a unit test to test `TestIdentity`

```
[TestClass]
public class MiscUnitTest {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task MyManager_TestIdentity_With_User_Should_Return_AdminRole() {
        //Arrange
        string username = "user";
        string expectedRole = "admin";
        var mockIMyRespository = new Mock<IMyRespository>();
        mockIMyRespository.Setup(p => p.GetRole(It.IsAny<string>())).
        ReturnsAsync(new RoleObject() {
            Name = expectedRole
        });

        var sut = new MyManager(mockIMyRespository.Object);

        //Act
        var result = await sut.TestIdentity(username);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result.Role);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedRole, result.Role.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not have ` public MyManager(IMyRespository myRepository) {
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
    }` inside MyManager :(

Comment: that was just an example meant to demonstrate the constructor injection concept. You can convert it to match your example if needed.

Comment: ok i got your point thanks , one query I'm using `ObjectFactory.Inject(mockIMyRespository.Object);` how it will work in case of constructor injection please help.

Comment: Again your examples don't show how or if you use `ObjectFactory` in your implementations so there is not much help I can provide. It would only be speculations. Note how I clearly stated my assumptions in my answer.